# Limit of named pipe readers

Tags: c, unix, pipe

(UNIX) I have 2 programs in C in which I use a named pipe (created by mkpipe, fopen etc.) to communicate. There is one writer and multiple readers for that pipe. 
Is there any way to set a maximum possible number of readers, in writer's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no such way to do that.